# How to set selected values on react-boostrap multi select?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have been trying something like this:

```
<FormControl componentClass="select" multiple value="['other1', 'other2']">
  <option value="other1">other1</option>
  <option value="other2">other2</option>
  <option value="other3">other3</option>
  <option value="other4">other4</option>
  <option value="other5">other5</option>
</FormControl>
```

But I can't get the syntax correct, and am not actually sure if its the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

> Note: You can pass an array into the value attribute, allowing you to
>   select multiple options in a select tag: .

From my original example, this is the correct way to do it:

```
<FormControl componentClass="select" multiple value={['other1', 'other2']}>
  <option value="other1">other1</option>
  <option value="other2">other2</option>
  <option value="other3">other3</option>
  <option value="other4">other4</option>
  <option value="other5">other5</option>
</FormControl>
```